# Filter on range of datetimes in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model with a field named `start_time` which is of type `DateTimeField`. I want to query a range which overlaps this field. Django filters contains a `DateFromToRangeFilter` filter which works perfectly for *dates* but not for *datetime* strings (unless I'm querying incorrectly). Here's what I've tried so far:

Created a `DatetimeFromToRangeFilter`:

```
class DatetimeRangeField(RangeField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = (
            forms.DateTimeField(),
            forms.DateTimeField())
        super(DatetimeRangeField, self).__init__(fields, *args, **kwargs)

    def compress(self, data_list):
        if data_list:
            start_datetime, stop_datetime = data_list
            if start_datetime:
                start_datetime = datetime.combine(start_datetime, time.min)
                if stop_datetime:
                    stop_datetime = datetime.combine(stop_datetime, time.max)
                    return slice(start_datetime, stop_datetime)
        return None

class DatetimeFromToRangeFilter(RangeFilter):
    field_class = DatetimeRangeField
```

Use this as a filter:

```
class TestRunFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    start_time = filters.DatetimeFromToRangeFilter()

    class Meta:
        model = models.TestRun
        fields = ['start_time',]
```

When I query the endpoint with `/test_runs/?start_time_0=2015-09-05` or `/test_runs/?start_time_0=2015-09-05%2000:00:00` it does nothing to filter the queryset.

When I change the filter to `django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter` the first query returns the appropriate queryset, the second query returns a null queryset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have some improper indentation, in comparison to the DateRangeField provided by django-filter.

In django_filters/fields.py:

```
        if start_date:
            start_date = datetime.combine(start_date, time.min)
        if stop_date:
            stop_date = datetime.combine(stop_date, time.max)
        return slice(start_date, stop_date)
```

In your code:

```
        if start_datetime:
            start_datetime = datetime.combine(start_datetime, time.min)
            if stop_datetime:
                stop_datetime = datetime.combine(stop_datetime, time.max)
                return slice(start_datetime, stop_datetime)
```

Try making the indentation levels match and that should take care of your problem.

Comment: Wow I should check the obvious things sometimes... thank you!

Comment: As a side comment I could have simply removed the combine statements since I have a full timestamp.